# Filewatcher is consuming most of PC resource

Tags: c#, sqlite, memory-leaks, filesystemwatcher

I am developing an application which tracks directory related changes on available drives of PC and save those changes in the sqlite DB. Everything in the below code is working fine as expected. But when I tested it by copying approx 100 directory and their nested directories together, it freeze the application and also freeze copy process of Windows OS.

I am not getting the way how to manage it because this code for bulk file copying is consuming most of the PC resource. Is there any why I can optimize it? rather setting "IncludeSubDirectories = False"?

```
class DirWatcher
{        
    private FileSystemWatcher dirWatcher = null;

    public void StartCapture()
    {
        string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

        foreach (string drive in drives)
        {
            DriveInfo driveInfo = new DriveInfo(drive);
            if (driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
            {
                //Director Watcher
                dirWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(drive);
                dirWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;


                dirWatcher.Created += dirWatcher_Created;
                dirWatcher.Deleted += dirWatcher_Created;
                dirWatcher.Renamed += dirWatcher_Renamed;

                dirWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                dirWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            }
        }
    }

    void dirWatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            saveToDB("Folder",
                                     e.ChangeType.ToString(),
                                     e.FullPath,
                                     Utility.UnixDTstamp(DateTime.Now).ToString(),
                                     Environment.UserName);

                        });
        }
        finally
        {
            dirWatcher.Renamed -= dirWatcher_Renamed;
        }
    }

    void dirWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                saveToDB("Folder",
                        e.ChangeType.ToString(),
                        e.FullPath,
                        Utility.UnixDTstamp(DateTime.Now).ToString(),
                        Environment.UserName);
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            dirWatcher.Created -= dirWatcher_Created;
        }
    }

    public void StopCapture()
    {
        dirWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        dirWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        dirWatcher.Dispose();
    }

    public void saveToDB(string DirOrFile, string action, string path, string time, string userName)
    {
        //SavetoDB code will be here.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code creates MANY FSW objects but only stops the LAST one created. You never store the other instances. Each time you call `StartCapture` you'll create more instances that monitor the same drives

Comment: Another problem is that you start a *new* task for each event. If you get 10K events, you'll create 10K tasks. Use an ActionBlock instead with a limited degree of parallelism (the default 1 is OK too) that will accept whatever you want to post to it and store it to SQLite. With a DOP=1 you won't even have to control concurrent write access to the SQLite file

Comment: 1) Should I use make it Singleton Class to prevent more object instance creation. 

2) In my application I am calling `StartCapture` only once. I am trying with ActionBlock as you said.

Comment: The problem isn't singleton, it's that you create X objects and store all instances in the *same* variable. This means that you keep only the last instance. You should store them in a list or array

Comment: Sir, How can i implement it, Any link that can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may be slowing down ( or even defeating) your program are attached drives on the network. I don't believe that you can successfully set a Filewatcher on these, especially if the drivers are LINUX based. And even if you could, it would be glacial in performance

I have also found Filewatcher to miss events when watching folder hierarchies. So in general, I'd say that you need to find or write a replacement for this functionality that is so flawed it should be deprecated. Perhaps a hook that lets you watch the windows message loop?